# Using Python and Pandas to generate trends from indicators

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, finance, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to determine what kinds of corrections a market makes in response to changes.
A simple version of this using Python, Pandas and matplotlib might look like:

```
from pandas import *
ts = read_csv("time_series.csv")

chng = ts / ts.shift(1)
chng.name="current"
f = chng.shift(-1)
f.name="future"
frame = concat([chng, f], axis=1)
frame.groupby(frame.current.round(2)).future.mean().plot()
```

For example if my data set had a strong habit of correcting changes back to the original value (within 1 tick) the output of the code above might show a negative correlation.

[image]

The problem with this method is that it can only show what the response is over a fixed time frame (i.e. I can change the amount that the future data set is shifted, but it can only be one value).
What I would like to do is divide the initial values into buckets and show a trendline for how each range of initial values was received over time (1 tick later, 3 ticks later, etc).

How could I go about doing that?

Comment: the title says "trends" and the body says "correction". what exactly are you looking for? because these are two different things

Comment: I mean trends. I just thought it was easier to describe by focusing on one possible trend, which could conceivably be correction.